# Create Setup Project DLL files Information

Tags: c#, installation

I finished a project.I am trying create a setup .
My Problem is that :after I create setup project dll files that I used in project added to same folder with my .exe file like

ApplicationFolder(Folder)
        Devexpress.Data.dll
        Devexpress.Util..dll
        .
        .
        project.exe

but I want to get it different folder.
like
ApplicationFolder(Folder)
        MYDLLFILES(Folder)
        project.exe(exe file)

how can I make this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is not only a problem of setup. unless you are already handling this in the app.config and/or with appdomain.assemblyresolve event your application will not work at all on the user's machines once those required references will not be available in the same folder if the .exe file.

Surely you could isolate every single file and tell the setup project where to put it but your program has to be modifief to then look for those files in those other locations.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally faced this problem today, I want to add some separate dll files into the setup package (I have to do this because I can't add reference of these dll files into my C# program , these dll files are of 3rd-party software).

I did as following:

Right click on Setup Project > Add > Assembly and then browse to dll which I need, then press OK button.

These dll files will be included into Setup project, and will be packaged into setup file also.

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Visual Studio setup projects will automatically include referenced DLLs for you so you won't be able to customize their location with these setup projects.

See also the following articles by DevExpress:

- [How to deploy WinForms applications on client machines](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A4.aspx)
- [How to distribute applications which use Developer Express .NET Windows Forms controls](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A240.aspx)

The second article explains how to register DLLs copied to a different location.

By the way we're also also deploying a big app using these VS setup projects and our base installation folder is full of DevExpress and other DLLs. I agree that it looks totally ugly and I'd also prefer a clean structure with a *lib* subfolder, but nobody cares about that. Customers don't start our application from the installation folder, they use the shortcuts.